# Why am I having overheating problems on HP Pavilion g6-1058er?

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, overheating

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit on my laptop  `HP Pavilion g6-1058er`  and I've got problems with it.

When I shut down or reboot my pc, when I turn it on again, my bios gives me this warning:

(something like this)

```
Your PC was shut down or rebooted because of overheating...
```

and also this problem was when I had Ubuntu 10.04 installed, when I'm working on Windows everything is ok.

Comment: I know it gives this message but HAS it overheated? what's the temperature?

Comment: Once it was okay.
Once, after the reboot, CPU temp was 68C.
maybe there is a problem with fan?

Comment: well 68C is not overheat! mine overheats at 93 or so. I've been at 89C as most. Is the fan always starting? remove the keyboard from the laptop and you will find the fan under there.

Comment: yes, fan always work,i hear it,and i see it

Answer (score 1):

Well i have a pavilion g6 (not the same model as yours) and i had the same problem!mostly with debian hut also with ubuntu if i remember correctly...anyway..
I solved my problem!just update your bios..If i remember correctly it was a bios bug..
Good luck;)